# When moving your units, is it possible to prevent them from automatically attacking aliens that are hidden by fog of war?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

If you tell a unit to move to a hex, and that hex is both covered by fog of war and also happens to have an alien on it, your unit will automatically attack the unit.

This is pretty irksome, especially when the unit you're moving is an explorer. If I tell an explorer to move to a hex, and I'm not aware that there is an alien on that hex, my intention as the player is simply to move my explorer, not engage in a risky combat that will threaten the life of my explorer if there happens to be an alien there.

In Alpha Centauri there was an option that let you cancel a unit's remaining movement if the movement order resulted in putting your unit next to an enemy unit. Is there a similar setting somewhere in Beyond Earth that cancels movement if it would result in such an unexpected attack?

Comment: I can't answer your question, but if you're a fellow Alpha Centauri player you're going to be sorely disappointed by the shallowness of Civ:BE in comparison. :(

Comment: I wasn't impressed with vanilla BE but Rising Tide has completely turned the game around for me - I'm a big fan these days :-)

Comment: I'll have to give it a look; I got the base game early and stopped paying attention shortly after, so I didn't even realise there was an expansion!

Comment: Is moving one hex at a time too much of a burden? I ask because I usually just automate my explorers (which means they die on occasions) because I simply couldn't be bothered to manage up to a dozen of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no game setting to prevent this behavior. Indeed it would be pretty nice to have it, but sadly not even Civ V provides it. There could be a mod for this setting, but I'm sure the only way to prevent your scout from encountering an alien in the fog of war is moving the scout just 1 hex at a time. This way you will see every unit next to you and you can take your 2. move, to move back.